# HDMI mirror display issues

Tags: hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, mirroring

I have an Alienware X51 desktop and want to set up mirror displays using the NVIDIA card built-in mini HDMI and the other regular HDMI to two different TVs. I have the latest drivers on the GTX555 video card.

Though both TVs have picture, it's only giving me the option of the extended desktop...The NVIDIA control panel only recognizes the TV hooked up through the mini HDMI and the Windows 7 display set up (though it shows both TVs) the mirror option does not even appear.

How / is this achievable please?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're saying. "both TVs have picture..." "control panel recognizes the TV hooked up through the mini HDMI and the Windows setup..." "It shows both TVs." 

How many displays are you trying to hook up to this card total? Are all monitors the same size?

Comment: 2 TVs in total. I can see image on both but I can see the extended desktop (not a mirror or clone display). Windows 7's display setup does not give me the option for the mirror display. Nvidia display panel shows only one tv hooked up (the one connected through the mini-HDMI)...thank you!

Comment: So you do not have a display hooked to it as well. Just the two TVs? It's not going to mirror the display because the TV's have different resolutions. The only thing you will be able to do is clone or extend.

Comment: Hi, I have just 2 Samsung TVs with same resolution. I understood mirror is the same as clone...? It's not allowing me to do either... Thanks for your help

Comment: The mini-HDMI goes to your dedicated graphics card and the main HDMI goes to on-board graphics. You hook two tv's up to both HDMI and get an extended screen. There is no problem here. The system is doing exactly what it should. You cannot clone or mirror the screens because they are using two different graphic devices. Honestly, I'm sure how they managed to make it extend. Cool feature though. In order to clone or mirror (which makes no sense to do), you will need to purchase an DVI to HDMI adapter. This issue has been solved. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_KSxsGaVHW8